How to interpret statements about individuals in the future if they might cease to exist?
I've been reading this book, and and stumbled upon a formula that I've been having a hard time interpreting.
In chapter 9 the author introduces the formula Gx=x, meaning that the individual x is always going to be x.
The way I understand the G operator from the book is that given a linear sequence of situations ..., s₋₁, sₒ, s₁, ... where sₘ is in the future of sₖ iff m > k, Gφ is true in the situation s iff φ is true in all future situations of s.
But how do you interpret a statement about an individual (constant) in a future where they might not exists anymore?
For example if x is my cat, then at the moment (sₒ) x=x is obviously true.
But if my poor cat suddenly died tomorrow (s₁) would it then be true that x=x a week from now?
Can x=x even be evaluated at a future sₘ of s₁?
Do individual constants even make sense in a temporal logic?
The system in the book seems to be similar to Prior's tense logic, although from what I could find TL is an extension of propositional logic and doesn't include predicates or individual constants.

One thought I had was that any statement about x in s must be vacuously true if x doesn't exists in s.
If x is the Balrog, then to disprove that x has wings you would have to show me a Balrog without wings.
Since Balrogs don't exist x has wings.
But the same argument would work to show that is doesn't have wings, so accepting this style of argument would make the reasoning inconsistent.

By Durin's beard, let me hear you utter that the Balrog of Morgoth is mere fiction and I shall cleave you in twain! Temporality is beyond my ken but Temporal Logic and Temporal Parts in the SEP might offer you some help.

You can perfectly understand the statement "Yesterday my cat died".

@MauroALLEGRANZA I think the your sentence makes sense, since at that point in time (yesterday) your cat existed and was dying.
But if you said "My cat likes tuna", I don't know if we could interpret it today since "your cat" doesn't exist anymore.

Ok, I think I might've found my misunderstanding.
According to this section of the article linked by J D, in FOTL in a moment in time t there is a local domain D_t of objects that exist.
But the interpretation of a constant in t, I_t(c), is an element of the global domain.
So it might be that I_t(c) = "my cat" even though "my cat" ∉ D_t, making c=c true in t even though ∃x(x=c) might be false.

@Knogger You might want to write up your self-obtained answer. If you can explain it to others, it will solidify your understanding and teach us something about temporal logic, as well as provide a mechanism for feedback. From the outside, I can say that the notion of local and global domains aligns nicely with the notion of contexts in relation to propositions, especially when verb tense and aspect are considered.

you should provide a quote, not a link. A link is not an acceptable part of a question.

@SwamiVishwananda Sorry, I wasn't aware of that since other questions also link to outside resources.
I'm not entirely sure how to meaningfully replace either of them by a quote though to be honest.

There are two incorrect assumptions about constants in FOTL (first order temporal logic) in my question.
I thought that the interpretation of constants in a model was fixed (similar to classical FOL) and that if the interpretation of a constant doesn't exist at a time t, something akin to a failure to refer might occur.
But constants are used much more flexible than that, a constant symbol for "my cat" might (sadly) refer to a different cat at different points in your life and you can make meaningful statements about objects that might not exist anymore/yet.
The domain D of a FOTL model can be split into a local domain Dₜ for each time instant t and the interpretation function Iₜ also depends on the time t.
But crucially Iₜ(c) ∈ D, so it's not necessarily also the case that Iₜ(c) ∈ Dₜ.
c needn't exists at time t to make a true statement about it.
Using presentist quantification (∃/∀ quantify over the local domain Dₜ instead of D) you can show that ⊨c=c, even though for some model M it might be the case that M, t ⊨ ¬∃x(x=c) for some t.

You are on the right lines. At any given time I am identical with myself. Leibniz's law says identical things have identical properties. But today's me does not have the same properties as yesterday's me. We would usually choose to describe this situation by saying some of my properties have changed, rather than saying I am a different individual. So we need to give 'me' a time index. Likewise with names and definite descriptions. There are several ways to accomplish this, which the SEP article describes.

Incidentally, this is similar to a situation that arises in modal logic where we can choose to quantify over individuals at a world, or over individuals across all possible worlds. Possibilism in modal logic roughly corresponds to eternalism in temporal logic. It makes the logic simpler in many ways, but it also makes the semantics rather more awkward.

Btw, you can accept your own answer after 48 hours.
